# Accord.NET throw "Index was outside the bounds of the array"

Tags: c#, accord.net

I was working on KNN from Accord.NET and I faced this error for some reason when I need to test model.

but this error message didn't help at all [(Index was outside the bounds of the array)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20940980/8581829) because this error happen in the library itself.

simple code with random data:

```
        using Accord.MachineLearning;

        double[][] inputs =
        {
            new double[] { 16, 2 ,0}, new double[] { 4, 5 ,1},
            new double[] { 16, 2 ,0}, new double[] { 4, 5 ,1},
            new double[] { 16, 2 ,0}, new double[] { 4, 5 ,1},
            new double[] { 16, 2 ,0}, new double[] { 4, 5 ,1},
            new double[] { 16, 2 ,0}, new double[] { 4, 5 ,1},
            new double[] { 16, 2 ,0}, new double[] { 4, 5 ,1},
            new double[] { 16, 2 ,0}, new double[] { 4, 5 ,1},
            new double[] { 16, 2 ,0}, new double[] { 4, 5 ,1},
            new double[] { 16, 2 ,0}, new double[] { 4, 5 ,1},
            new double[] { 16, 2 ,0}, new double[] { 4, 5 ,1},
            new double[] { 16, 2 ,0}, new double[] { 4, 5 ,1},
            new double[] { 16, 2 ,0}, new double[] { 4, 15 ,1},
        };

        int[] outputs =
        {
            0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
            0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
            0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
            0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 9
        };

        var knn = new KNearestNeighbors(k: 15);
        knn.Learn(inputs, outputs);

        //test
        var t = new double[] { 16, 2, 0 };
        int answer = knn.Decide(t);
```

and here the exception:

[image: exception]

but I found way around and I share solution with you below :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after many days and after implementing this simple sample I found that output array should have continues range values (encoded : 0,1,2,3,....) .
so here `9` is why that bug happen here

```
    int[] outputs =
    {
        0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
        0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
        0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
        0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2
    };
```

Comment: Many days? Why could you then post your answer at the same time as as the question?

Comment: I found the solution and I want to share it specially that error message doesn't help at all